# Taking away certain commas etc in a toString

Tags: java, string, arraylist, tostring

Heres my toString method currently

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < knowledgeD.size(); i++ ){

            w = knowledgeD.get(i).get(0);
            y = knowledgeD.get(i).get(1);



        string.append("{true@" +  w + ","+" " +"false@"  + w.complement() + "}" + "@" + y);
           string.append("" +","+" ");
         //{{true@1/4, false@3/4}@1/2, {true@2/3, false@1/3}@3/16, {true@4/5, false@1/5}@5/16}    
         //{{true@1/4, false@3/4}@1/2, {true@2/3, false@1/3}@3/16, {true@4/5, false@1/5}@5/16, }


    }
    String s = string.toString();
    String g = "{" + s + "}";
    return g;
```

This returns g which is the second comment under the string.append, I need it to return the comment above, but i can't for the life of me work out how to get rid of the comment on the last string piece and just have a bracket there instead, since this Arraylist is updateable so the last part of the string i.e. the

```
{true@4/5, false@1/5}@5/16, }
```

was added too it would need to have a comma there and follow the pattern of the toString.

I have no idea how to get rid of this comma just for the last string part, can anyone shed some light.

Comment: You're kinda ruining the purpose of a `StringBuilder` with using the `+` operator on `String`s.

Comment: You can chain StringBuilder.append("...").appened("...")... (offtopic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of appending the comma *after* each iteration, append *before* each iteration *except the first one*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < knowledgeD.size(); i++ ){
       if (i != 0) {
           string.append(", ");
       }
       w = knowledgeD.get(i).get(0);
       y = knowledgeD.get(i).get(1);
       string.append("{true@" +  w + ","+" " +"false@"  + w.complement() + "}" + "@" + y);
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out

```
string.append("{true@" +  w + ...
```

is better written as

```
string.append("{true@").append(w).append(...
```